# Why do these objects (from a generator) change when I add them to a list?

Tags: python

So I'm trying to get objects from a generator and add them to a list.  But the moment I add them to the list, the list fills with null objects instead of the objects I've added.  Why is that?

This code

```
#!/usr/bin/python

# Create a graph with 5 nodes
from snap import *

G = TUNGraph.New()

for i in range(5):
    G.AddNode(i)

# Ids of these nodes are 0, 1, 2, 3, 4
for node in G.Nodes():  # G.Nodes() is a generator
    print node.GetId()

lst = []
for node in G.Nodes():
    lst.append(node)

print
# All of the nodes magically change to have ID -1
print [node.GetId() for node in lst]

print
# The nodes in the original graph are unchanged
for i in G.Nodes():
    print i.GetId()
```

produces the output

```
0
1
2
3
4

[-1, -1, -1, -1, -1]

0
1
2
3
4
```

Comment: Try adding `print id(node)` in your second loop.  I suspect (but don't know) that the `Nodes()` iterator is returning the same object each time.  If all the ids printed are the same, it definitely is.

Comment: Yeah it is.  That would explain a lot.  I wonder why that is.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

OK!  In a comment on the original, we established that

```
for node in G.Nodes():  # G.Nodes() is a generator
    print node.GetId()
    print id(node)  #  NEW LINE HERE
```

prints the same thing for `id(node)` each time.

That means the generator is returning the **same object** each time, and mutates it between calls.  The "objects" in your list are all the same object, and its state reflects whatever internal fiddling the `Nodes()` implementation does under the covers.

I think this is bad design, although I haven't used SNAP so can't be sure.  It's a micro-efficiency trick I've seen too often.  When CPython does something like this internally, it first checks to see that the reference count on the yielded object is 1.  If, and only if, it's 1, CPython knows it holds the **only** reference to the yielded object, and so it's safe to mutate it.  But if the refcount is greater than 1, CPython creates a new object to yield (because the user may be holding on to the last one yielded - as @eeeeeeeeee does in his sample code).

I'd complain to the package authors about this behavior.  It's at best confusing and error-prone :-(